# Leaflet with position:fixed leaves gray trail after scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, leaflet

I'm trying to make site containing two divs:

- left, Y-scrollable with content
- right, not moving (position fixed), containing just a label and leaflet map

When I am scrolling the page, leaflet leaves gray trail, which I want to get rid of.

All I have found here (at stackoverflow) is **map.invalidateSize()**, but it did not help me.

[Watch full jsfiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSM49/3/).

HTML:

```
<div id="map">      
</div>

<div id="content">
Heres the text<br />
    ...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#map{
    width: 400px; 
    height: 400px; 

    position: fixed; 
    left: 60%; 
    top: 30%;   
}
```

JS:

```
    // create a map in the "map" div, set the view to a given place and zoom
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    // add an OpenStreetMap tile layer
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    }).addTo(map);

    window.map = map;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        window.map.invalidateSize();
    })
})
```

Comment: Hey, I just saw that. `background: transparent;` is better to use rather then `none`, just wanted to let you know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to `background: none;`

```
#map{
    width: 400px; 
    height: 400px; 
    background: none;
    position: fixed; 
    left: 60%; 
    top: 30%;   
}
```

Comment: Well it does the trick, when background of the page is white. In real site the background is not that simple :/

Comment: Is there an image as the background or it scrolls over divs and stuff?

Comment: How about `background: none;`

Comment: There's a gradient as a background of site, and the div scrolls over all the content

Comment: Background: none does the trick, edit your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a lot!